# Why do we need to register UDF in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

Why do we need to register user defined function if we could still use this:

```
def func(num):
return num*5.2

dataframe\
    .select(func(dataframe.rowName))\
    .show()
```

Are there any benefits or?

Answer (score 1):

Registering the function as a UDF allows the function to be serialized by the driver and shared throughout the cluster. In your example the function is only defined on a single machine (the driver).

Comment: What do you mean by 'serialized by the driver'? I'm using a laptop with 6 cores so... does that mean that only one of the cores is used and 5 others are idle?